# How do I get SFTP/FTP setup

Tags: sftp, vsftpd

So I have another question, I would like to setup FTP/SFTP I know that ftp is not as secure but what I am trying to accomplish is to allow a user (web) to be able to login via sftp or ftp and upload/publish directly to the /var/www/html folder.

Comment: In this day and age FTP without encryption should not even be considered.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will not use FTP without encryption

Answer (score 1):

For ftp use vsftpd or proftpd, while sftp functionality is included in openssh your standard ssh daemon. Check tutorials on how to change default directory to /var/www/html. Here is one for openssh https://debian-administration.org/article/590/OpenSSH_SFTP_chroot_with_ChrootDirectory . Set the default ownership of the files to something your webserver can read. If you have Selinux running, then you will need to create special configurations, check CentOS Selinux page https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux.

Comment: Thank you Pozzo-Balbi, I am going to check these links out. I am trying to figure out the best way to have my current IIS webpages moved to this new Centos 7 VM

Comment: @twitchedout you might also want to look into setting up virtual hosts and run each website as a separate user.

Comment: @Shadur Thanks for the information. I will consider that to. I just want to be able to get this up and running for now to see about messing around with other things